# Make checkbox checked when db is updated in angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, typescript, angular-meteor

I am listing some menus from settings collection with check box. 
[image: like this]

When I check a menu it is pushed into user collection with that menu's id.

But when I navigate to other page or refresh the page the checked check box gets unchecked itself. I want to avoid that.

Here the menus are listed from settings collection but the checked condition is checked from users collection, whether the menu is pushed or not.

My settings collection looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "GdfaHPoT5FXW78aw5",
    "name" : "URL",
    "description" : "https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/",
    "type" : "url",
    "tag" : "This is a demo of an Url selected",
    "status" : false
}
```

And my user collection like this:

```
"settings" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "GdfaHPoT5FXW78api",
        "name" : "Image",
        "description" : "uploads/images-ihDszYA8xqHSGfBo5-prof.jpg",
        "tag" : "This is a demo for an image",
        "type" : "image",
        "status" : false
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "GdfaHPoT5FXW78aw5",
        "name" : "URL",
        "description" : "https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/",
        "tag" : "This is a demo of an Url selected",
        "type" : "url",
        "status" : true
    }]
```

My HTML goes like this:

```
  <div layout-gt-sm="row"  ng-repeat="detail in settingCtrl.generalSettings">
        <md-checkbox aria-label="Checkbox 1"  ng-model="detail.status" ng-change="dynamicSettingsCtrl.getClicked(detail._id)">

               <p> {{detail.name}} {{ detail.data.cb1 }}</p>
        </md-checkbox>
    </div>
```

This is my client side js:

```
self.getClicked = (settingId) => {
    self.dataArry = {};
    self.dataChk = {};

    // self.currentUser = {};

    console.log(settingId)

    Meteor.call("updateSettings", settingId, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            ToastService.getToastbox($mdToast, 'Something went error!Unable to add details', 'error-toast');
        } else {
            //self.currentUser = {};
            ToastService.getToastbox($mdToast, 'Details added successfully !', 'success-toast');
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my server side js:

```
updateSettings: function(generalValue) {
    let userId = Meteor.userId();
    let settingsDetails = GeneralSettings.findOne({"_id": generalValue});
    Meteor.users.update(
        {_id: userId},
        {
            $push: 
            {
                "settings": 
                {
                    "_id": generalValue,
                    "name": settingsDetails.name,
                    "description": settingsDetails.description,
                    "tag": settingsDetails.tag,
                    "type": settingsDetails.type,
                    "status": settingsDetails.status
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: post you controller pls.

Comment: posted my client side js and server side js

Comment: you are probably not loading the data from the DB, that's why refreshing it will not show the thick. Still missing the controller ctrl (which is most important). Is the set of the checkbox actually saved on the DB?

Comment: yes when checked it is saved!! how can i load the data from db.. since listing is from one collection and checked is from another collection..how can i delete the pushed data when unchecked